# Is it safe to add a floor to my garage attic?

Tags: flooring, roof, attic

It looks like the roof is made with trusses. Is there any way to add some flooring to store some boxes?
[image]

Comment: My guess is that you're not storing boxes. You're storing the contents of boxes. How much weight? What kind of floor? It could well be that the weight of your floor exceeds the weight of the storage items. We'll need you to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Generally not recommended.  Trusses are not engineered to carry additional weight on their bottom chords.  There are "storage" trusses that can be specified when the house is built that will be able to carry the additional load.

Comment: I agree, but millions of garages have a few hundred lbs. of junk scattered around in them. I've never seen modern trusses fail because of it, even my snow-heavy region. It just takes some sense to do it safely.

Comment: Indeed, they are over-engineered, but at the end of the day it's a game of buckaroo.